# SPARQL individuals queries for Pizza ontology

Tags: semantic-web, owl, ontology, protege

I wrote this query but it does't work. Anyone knows what is the problem.

```
PREFIX : <http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2009/pizza.owl#>
SELECT ?X ?Y
        WHERE {?X :hasCountryOfOrigin "Italy".
               ?Y :hasCalorificValue "400"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Pizza ontology tutorial [here](http://mowl-power.cs.man.ac.uk/protegeowltutorial/resources/ProtegeOWLTutorialP4_v1_3.pdf), there are two main issues with your query:

1. `hasCountryOfOrigin` is an object property, thus, the values can't be literals. Italy is an individual, thus, you have to use the correct URI, probably `http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2009/pizza.owl#Italy`
2. The data property `hasCalorificValue` has values of type integer, i.e. literals should be used like `"400"^^xsd:integer` (or maybe `xsd:int`, depends on what you've chosen in Protege)
3. Both triple patterns in your query are not connected, i.e. no shared variable. I don't see the goal of your query.

```sql
PREFIX : <http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2009/pizza.owl#>
SELECT ?X ?Y
        WHERE {?X :hasCountryOfOrigin :Italy.
               ?Y :hasCalorificValue "400"^^xsd:integer}
```

Comment: I am talking about this tutorial [link](http://mowl-power.cs.man.ac.uk/protegeowltutorial/resources/ProtegeOWLTutorialP4_v1_3.pdf). Is there anyway to find all the topping have 'hasCountryOfOrigin' Italy. For finding calorie, I try ' ?Y :hasCalorificValue "400"^^xsd:Integer' but it didn't work.

Comment: I updated my answer. It still remains unclear what you want to achieve with the query since the variables are not connected.

Comment: I know that these two values are not connected. I was practicing, I don't seek to achieve anything by this query. However, I tried your answer in the Protege, SPARQL Query tab but still I didn't get any answer.

Comment: Can you share the ontology please? E.g on Gist, PasteBin or something

Comment: Thanks, so much, I found out my problem. I forgot to delete my question here.